# Wordpress error open_basedir restriction in effect. File is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, wordpress, open-basedir

After trying a migration from another domain back to:

> http://fabiolagreco.web1007.kinghost.net/

I probably mistyped the command line in PHP My Admin, to search and overwrite the domain addresses and now the wordpress will not load. It keeps showing the following error:

> **Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/fabiola/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/fabiolagreco/:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php:./) in /home/fabiolagreco/www/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1421**

Site URL:

> http://fabiolagreco.web1007.kinghost.net/

Answer (score 0):

Well, your site crashes my browser...
But, I have a few ideas:

1. One, your host provider don't allow to do that.
2. The migration was not made correctly... this means that serialized data is corrupted (paths and urls).
3. Maybe this is due a wrong "transient"
4. Or maybe you should define your WP_TEMP_DIR in config.php